# How to properly configure an npm package of .jsx components

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, jsx, es6-modules

I am setting up a react component package that exports several .jsx components. These components will be used on multiple sites at my company. I am having a lot of problems that seem to be caused by ESModules. I can't find any good guides that show how to properly package up all my components into an npm module to be used by other applications.

in my package.json i have

```json
"main": "src/index.js",
"type": "module",
```

My index.js simply exports my components

```js
export { default as Accordion } from './components/Accordion/index.jsx';
export { default as Alert } from './components/Alert/index.jsx';
export { default as BackToTop } from './components/BackToTop/index.jsx';
...
```

All my components are typical default export react function components

```
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cn from 'classnames;

export default function Alert() {
...
}
```

If i try to utilize my package locally by installing it in a Vite app by using a local reference in package.json `"@mycompany/mypackage": "file:../mypackage"` everything works just fine. I can import and use components

```
import {Alert} from '@mycompany/mypaackage`
```

However when i try to install it as an actual package i get errors like

```
prop-types does not provide an export named 'default'
```

I searched around a little and it looks like i needed to change all my external imports to look like: `import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';` to work with CJS. However that still did not fix the issue because it seems like the ReactTransitionGroup package also does an import from `prop-types` and then that module would be throwing the error.

My company will be using both Vite and Next for different applications.

When i try to use my components inside of a Next.js app i have to include the package inside the `transpilePackages` setting in the next config or it will not work.

I played around a little bit with trying to use babel to transpile my code but the problem there was babel would transform all my `.jsx` files into `.js` files - but it would not transform any local file imports. So one of my components would still be trying to do a local import with .jsx file extensions `import {Alert} from '../Alert/index.jsx`

According to what i could find the new ESM standard requires file extensions to be used when doing imports so i was unable to figure that out